# How does the rod's centre of mass change while falling?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, classical-mechanics, rotational-kinematics, moment-of-inertia, moment

Which force displaces the rod's centre of mass? The body is rigid and surface rough. And how can we apply  conservation of energy in calculating angular velocity in presence of friction?[image]

Answer (score 0):

[image: Falling rod]

The way you describe it, there's enough friction for the bottom end $P$ of the rod to remain stationary. The rough surface and point $P$ then act like a hinge.

If the rod is perfectly vertical, i.e. the angle between the rod and the horizontal is $\theta=\frac{\pi}{2}$, the rod is in perfect equilibrium and **will not fall**.

But is we introduce a small perturbation, so that $\theta<\frac{\pi}{2}$, a torque $\tau$ is introduced *about the point $P$*, caused by the weight vector $\vec{mg}$ no longer passing through $P$. With $L$ the length of the rod we get:

$$\tau=\frac{L}{2}mg\cos\theta$$

(Note indeed that for $\theta=\frac{\pi}{2}$, $\cos\theta=0$, so there's no accelerating torque in that situation)

This torque cause angular acceleration $\ddot{\theta}$ about $P$. According to Newton for rotating bodies and with $I$ the moment of inertia of the rod *about the point $P$*:

$$\tau=I\ddot{\theta}$$

With both equations we have:

$$I\ddot{\theta}=\frac{L}{2}mg\cos\theta$$

This is the *equation of motion* of the rod.

> And how can we apply conservation of energy in calculating angular
>   velocity in presence of friction?

The change in potential energy $\Delta U$ between initial and final state is:

$$\Delta U=mg\frac{L}{2}$$

Because $\frac{L}{2}$ is the change in height of the centre of gravity of the rod.

The change in kinetic energy $\Delta K$, assuming the final angular velocity is $\dot{\theta}$:

$$\Delta K=\frac12 I\dot{\theta}^2$$

Find $\dot{\theta}$ from conservation of energy:

$$\Delta U=\Delta K$$

$$\frac12 I\dot{\theta}^2=mg\frac{L}{2}$$
$$\dot{\theta}=\sqrt{\frac{mgL}{I}}$$